# distribution of mixed populations

Tags: statistics

Suppose my samples are drawn from two populations, X~exponential(l1) and Y~exponential(l2) in the proportion of 80% and 20%, respectively. Now I want to know what is the median of my drawn samples? I know if X and Y are two exponential distributions with different lambda, then X+Y is no longer an exponential distribution. So should I approach this question from what is the density of 0.8X+0.2Y which has available result, or more conveniently, the density is now just 0.8*f(x)+0.2*f(y)?

My intuition is the first one, however, simulation results show the median is equivalent to the second approach. I am confused.

Comment: The random variables $X+Y$ and $0.8X+0.2Y$ are quite unrelated to the question. Instead you need to solve for the unknown $m$, the equation $$0.8P(X\leqslant m)+0.2P(Y\leqslant m)=0.5.$$

Comment: Make sense. 
It's the first time I use this web for questions, and i don't even know who answered my question and how to thank you.

Comment: To understand this, it means my sample does not come from a new distribution, but rather, it's just a weighted average of known distributions. Am I correct?